# Python code not working as intended

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I started learning Python < 2 weeks ago.

I'm trying to make a function to compute a 7 day moving average for data. Something wasn't going right so I tried it without the function.

```
moving_average = np.array([])
i = 0
for i in range(len(temp)-6):
    sum_7 = np.array([])
    avg_7 = 0    
    missing = 0    
    total = 7    
    j = 0    
    for j in range(i,i+7):    
        if pd.isnull(temp[j]):    
            total -= 1    
            missing += 1    
        if missing == 7:    
            moving_average = np.append(moving_average, np.nan)    
            break    
    if not pd.isnull(temp[j]):    
        sum_7 = np.append(sum_7, temp[j])    
    if j == (i+6):    
        avg_7 = sum(sum_7)/total    
        moving_average = np.append(moving_average, avg_7)
```

If I run this and look at the value of `sum_7`, it's just a single value in the numpy array which made all the `moving_average` values wrong. But if I remove the first `for` loop with the variable `i` and manually set `i = 0` or any number in the range of the data set and run the exact same code from the inner for loop, `sum_7` comes out as a length 7 numpy array. Originally, I just did `sum += temp[j]` but the same problem occurred, the total sum ended up as just the single value.

I've been staring at this trying to fix it for 3 hours and I'm clueless what's wrong. Originally I wrote the function in R so all I had to do was convert to python language and I don't know why `sum_7` is coming up as a single value when there are two for loops. I tried to manually add an index variable to act as `i` to use it in the `range(i, i+7)` but got some weird error instead. I also don't know why that is.

https://gyazo.com/d900d1d7917074f336567b971c8a5cee

https://gyazo.com/132733df8bbdaf2847944d1be02e57d2

Comment: Can you give other relevant parts of the code? the variable `temp` is uninitialized in your example.

Comment: Setting the values of `i` and `j` before using them in the `for` loop is meaningless.

Comment: What sort of data are you averaging?

Comment: Additionally, the test `if j == (i+6):` will always be true. You can omit it completely.

Comment: I have the last statement if j == (i+6) because I want it to compute the sum and average only on the last iteration on the for loop.

The temp variable is one column of a data frame

Comment: I mainly want to know why the sum_7 numpy array only has a length of 1 when there are two for loops, and 7 when i set i manually and run the for j in range(i, i+7) code and below

Comment: @Skywind555 there's only 1 `for` loop as far as this variable is concerned. It is re-initialized at each iteration.

Comment: @Skywind555 as I said, the test is _always_ true, since at the end of the inner for loop, `j == i+6` no matter what.

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand. In the beginning of the second for loop if i = 0, j = 0. At the end of the first iteration j is still 0, and will not equal (i+6)=6.

I have it set so that I compute the sum and average only on the last iteration. I have the if statement there to make sure this calculation happens on the last iteration. This has nothing to do with my question because this part is included in both scenarios. Could insert a screenshot to indicate exactly what I'm talking about.

Comment: No, `j` is incremented at each iteration of the inner loop, and *retains its value*. Also the `break` does nothing since the loop can't have more than 7 iterations. Please experiment with it - print the values of the variables at each point.

Answer (score 2):

Hey you can using rolling() function and mean() function from pandas.
Link to the documentation :
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rolling.html

```
df['moving_avg'] = df['your_column'].rolling(7).mean()
```

This would give you some NaN values also, but that is a part of rolling mean because you don't have all past 7 data points for first 6 values.

Comment: This answer is not complete. Please provide some more context.

Comment: Oh, that's pretty neat. Thanks for the heads up. Now I just want to know why the mentioned code isn't working as intended.

Comment: Hey @Skywind555 can you show us your dataframe? If you want to calculate the moving average on a particular column then you will have to specify it.
    
    moving_avg = df['your_column'].rolling(7).mean()

Comment: I don't care about computing the moving average at this point, that was just the context of the code. What I want to know is, why in one screen shot the output doesn't give what I want and the other one with one less for loop, manually specifying the variable does. I don't understand why, and I want to know why. Knowing why will help me understand and improve my overall understanding of python

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you misindented the important line:

```
moving_average = np.array([])
i = 0
for i in range(len(temp)-6):
    sum_7 = np.array([])
    avg_7 = 0    
    missing = 0    
    total = 7    
    j = 0    
    for j in range(i,i+7):    
        if pd.isnull(temp[j]):    
            total -= 1    
            missing += 1    
        if missing == 7:    
            moving_average = np.append(moving_average, np.nan)    
            break    
    # The following condition should be indented one more level
    if not pd.isnull(temp[j]):
        sum_7 = np.append(sum_7, temp[j])
    #^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    if j == (i+6):
        # this ^ condition does not do what you meant 
        # you should use a flag instead
        avg_7 = sum(sum_7)/total    
        moving_average = np.append(moving_average, avg_7)
```

Instead of a flag you can use a *for-else* construct, but this is not readable. Here's [the relevant documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops).

---

Shorter way to do this:

```
moving_average = np.array([])
for i in range(len(temp)-6):
    ngram_7 = [t for t in temp[i:i+7] if not pd.isnull(t)]
    average = (sum(ngram_7) / len(ngram_7)) if ngram_7 else np.nan
    moving_average = np.append(moving_average, average)
```

This could be refactored further:

```
def average(ngram):
    valid = [t for t in temp[i:i+7] if not pd.isnull(t)]
    if not valid:
        return np.nan
    return sum(valid) / len(valid)

def ngrams(seq, n):
    for i in range(len(seq) - n):
        yield seq[i:i+n]

moving_average = [average(k) for k in ngrams(temp, 7)]
```

Comment: Because it behaves identically it doesn't do what it's supposed to do... I copy pasted this and it runs exactly the same. If I take a look at the sum_7 it's still of length 1 which causes moving_average to compute the average of a single value when it should be computing the average of 7 values at once.

https://gyazo.com/88c89908a23779ca2f36eedac599e552

If you take a look at the screenshots I posted up top that's my question. Why is it that for one instance I have a length 7 in sum_7 and in the other it's length 1

Comment: Thank you, I didn't catch the indentation error that solves everything. I'll read your suggestion about how to make it better when I wake up tomorrow this was keeping me up all night til 8 am.